# Change of entropy of a thermal reservoir

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

How to calculate/derive the change in entropy of a heat reservoir as function of its internal energy? If the constant temperature of heat reservoir is T, and

$$ S(U_0)=S_0,$$
what is $$ S(U)? $$

Answer (score 1):

For a reservoir of finite thermal inertial, the change in entropy is $$MC\ln{(T_f/T_i)}=MC\ln{\left[\frac{(T_i+\frac{Q}{MC})}{T_i}\right]}$$

Here's a hint:  What is the limit of this as the thermal inertial of the reservoir MC becomes infinite?

Comment: Thanks! About this heat Q, is it equal to the change in internal energy? Can the volume of heat reservoir change and thus can it do work?

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that the reservoir is an incompressible liquid.

Comment: Or we could assume that the reservoir is at constant pressure, in which case $Q=MC_p\Delta T=\Delta H$.  Either way one arrives at the same result.